# Guardar, na foto, as coordenadas do local onde foi tirada

Tags: android, geolocalização, gps

Gostaria que na minha aplicação ao tirar uma foto, que essa foto guarde as coordenadas de localização nos detalhes da foto, isso seria possível?

---

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE.);
intent.putExtra(String.valueOf(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT), uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

desta forma que faço a chamada da câmera, a principio como pegar a localização ainda não sei

Comment: eu fiz assim,
eu tirei a foto, no momento da foto pego a localização,
e em uma tabela salvo nome_foto, lat_foto, long_foto e mais infos necessárias.
ai dps montei uma lista com as imagens, e exibe no maps bem em cima da localização.
vc sabe pegar a localização, usar a intent da câmera e tudo mais?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Em relação ao armazenamento de dados na imagem:**

De uma olhada nesses links talvez ajude:

- [geo-tagging-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740503/geo-tagging-in-android)
- [taking-picture-and-geotag-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9898321/taking-picture-and-geotag-it)
- [geotagging-photos-after-using-camera-intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587070/geotagging-photos-after-using-camera-intent)

Existe uma classe: [ExifInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface.html) que possibilita a inserção de TAGs com meta informações dentro de uma imagem JPEG, dependendo da que quer criar vale a pena armazenar essas informações na própria imagem.

**Em relação a obtenção da localização:**

Adicione as seguintes permissões em seu manifest xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Segue um código que obtém a localização de forma simples sem a necessidade de escutar por uma calback, qualquer coisa de uma olhada no [guia Android para obter a localização](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

```
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = (Location) lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

Qualquer coisa poste comentários,
Abs.

Comment: Estou Conseguindo pegar a localização, então deveria adicionalá
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(/sdcard/photo/photoname.jpg);
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE,String.valueOf(latitudeValueInDecimal));
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE,String.valueOf(longitudeValueInDecimal));
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LATITUDE_REF,"N");
exif.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_GPS_LONGITUDE_REF,"W");
exif.saveAttributes();
e a onde tem o caminho, passo o caminho de minha foto, modificando a localização dela, isso?

Comment: Segui o exemplo que tem no link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13587070/geotagging-photos-after-using-camera-intent, existe um formato correto para adicionar a localização na tag.
Aqui nessa resposta o mecanismo do Exif é explicado um pouco melhor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10685694/1408832.